# Kendo Grid editable row issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have reproduced the issue I am facing in a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/nq0icE).

I have a kendo-grid with editable rows.

1. Click edit & click on the value for the column 'Units In Stock', causes the alert pop-up to fire twice.
2. Click on cancel & then click on the same column again, the pop-up opens only once.

Why does this happen & how do I get around this issue, so the pop-up opens only once, even when the row is on edit mode.

```
$scope.grid.options = {
dataSource: $scope.dataSource,
pageable: true,
height: 550,
toolbar: ["create"],
columns: [
    "ProductName",
    { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
    { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "120px", template: '<a href="" ng-click="test(dataItem.UnitsInStock)">{{dataItem.UnitsInStock}}</a>'},
    { field: "Discontinued", width: "120px" },
    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
editable: "inline"
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observer behavior is caused by the fact that even though the field is non-editable, the whole edit row is still built when the Grid is in inline editing mode, so the click event handler gets attached twice.

The most straightforward workaround is to call `stopImmediatePropagation()` on the event data object. Here is a [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) doc for the same.

Check out this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/wtpnujzLz35kaHFasfae).